# Can't upload file via API in React JS

Tags: reactjs, image, file, axios, upload

I'm trying to send data via api using axios in React JS.
My data is accepted, the ad is created successfully, there is no error in the media section, but in the end, The media section of the created ad is empty.
I don't know where I went wrong

mainApi.jsx file:

```
export const privateApi2 = axios.create({
  baseURL: BaseURL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenValue}`,
    UUID: userIdValue,
  }
})
```

userApi.jsx file

```
export const createPost ={
  async postCreatePost(postInfo){
    try{
      const response = await privateApi2.post(`${APP_USER_PREFIX}/create/post`,postInfo);
      return response.data;
    }
    catch(error){
      console.error(error);
    }
   
  }
}
```

createPost.jsx file:

```
  const [postInformation, setPostInformation] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    categoryId: "",
    price: "",
    media: "",
    currency: "1",
    country: "",
    city: "",
    fields: "",
    district: "",
    tags: "",
    isGuaranteed: "0",
    showAddress: "0",
  });
```

I fill the information in the state with the onchange function.

```
  const handleFileChange = (fileList) => {
    const files = fileList.map((file) => file.blobFile);
    setPostInformation({ ...postInformation, media: files });
  };
```

create function:

```
  const handleCreatePost = async () => {
    formData.append("title", postInformation.title);
    formData.append("description", postInformation.description);
    formData.append("categoryId", postInformation.categoryId);
    formData.append("price", postInformation.price);
    formData.append("currency", postInformation.currency);
    formData.append("country", postInformation.country);
    formData.append("city", postInformation.city);
    formData.append("district", postInformation.district);
    formData.append("isGuaranteed", postInformation.isGuaranteed);
    formData.append("showAddress", postInformation.showAddress);

    postInformation.media && postInformation.media.forEach((file) => {
      formData.append("media", file);
    });
    postInformation.tags.forEach((tag) => {
      formData.append("tags[]", tag);
    });
    Object.entries(postInformation.fields).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      formData.append(`fields[${key}]`, value);
    });
    try {
      const response = await createPost.postCreatePost(formData);
      console.log("respose create post ", response);
      if(response.status === 200){
        toast.success("post created successfully.");
      }
      onNext();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      toast.error(error.message);
    }
  };
```

```
<Uploader
  multiple
  listType="picture"
  defaultFileList={fileList}
  action="//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"
  onChange={handleFileChange}
>
  <button style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}>
    <FaCamera className="uploadIcon" />
    <p>upload photo</p>
  </button>
</Uploader>
```

backend is laravel